# unclear target of negation of にならない

Tags: negation

> 嘘をつけ。本物のブロンドはもっとナチュラルだし、そんな不自然な金色にはならん。

that's a lie, real blonde (hair) is more natural, THAT kind of of golden (hair colour) totally cannot be (real)?

...にはならん = not 本物/ナチュラル at all? The golden hair colour is what it is, so it would be hard to negate that directly.

---

On a side note, is there any difference between the literal にならない - aka the negative of になる、 and the negation usage of にならない (話にならない, 洒落にならな.. 問題にならない , etc)

I guess random sentence could be used for the literal meaning.

「パパみたいにならないでね」という母親のグチが子どもをダメにする

Is there any perceived difference? Don't become like your dad vs You're not like your dad at all(doubt this is the case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an example of misuse of になる／にならない that is commonly used by (mostly) young people working in convenience stores and family restaurants (according to NHK's link below). The correct word should be です／ではない（じゃない）. So if we are to correct the sentence in question, it would become:

> 本物のブロンドはもっとナチュラルだし、そんな不自然な金色**じゃない**。

In other words, the speaker is saying, "that kind of unnatural golden hair is not natural blonde at all." Please see [「～になります」](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/074.html)？ by NHK Broadcasting Culture Research Institute for details.

According to this link, although the verb なる has so many meanings, if a に is used it means either of the following:

1. The result of a change or transition appears. Examples:

> 大人になる。冬になる。中止になる。合計すると二千円になる。

2. Fulfills a certain role as a result. Examples:

> 番組制作の参考になる。励みになる。

Going back to the original sentence, 「本物のブロンドはもっとナチュラルだし、そんな不自然な金色」 is not a result of some kind of change or transition, nor does it fulfill a certain role. Therefore, にならない should have been じゃない in this case.

Note: If for example the speaker is saying that the second person dyed his or her hair blonde, then in this situation にならない could be used. Example:

> 髪染めを使ったんだろう？本物のブロンドはそんな不自然な金色にはならない

Comment: If you don't mind, for something like this "マイナスがマイナスになっても足し算だからマイナスなんだぞ".  - " even though negative is negative (fulfills the role of negative?), adding negatives is still negative!"  what exactly is イナスがマイナスになっても implying here?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you sure that comment is for my answer? I didn't write anything like that.

Comment: i was wondering how you would apply one of those two definitions or になるto this statement

Comment: Not sure, but I think the first definition would apply because the speaker is talking about a result : adding two negative number results to another negative number.

Comment: hm,  i was wondering if i was missing something with になる for the statement to end with ても、as there was no obvious reason why 算だからマイナスなんだ would contrast against the the what you would expect from the first statement,  if anything it is what you would expect.  Compare to マイナスがマイナスになって、足し算だからマイナスなんだぞ？